# Why should a queryString variable in an apex batch class declared as global?

Tags: apex, batch

Every documentation on batch apex class shows the queryString variable declared as global. Is there a specific reason for doing so??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not need to be global or indeed there at all.

You can use compile-time checked static SOQL in the start method instead which is often a cleaner approach e.g.:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator([select Name from Account]);
}
```

and the class and methods can be public instead of global.